# how to add title tag to individual GWT Datagrid headers?

Tags: gwt, datagrid

is this possible without adding other libraries?

the grid table was added into a  Simple panel. Newbie in gwt here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When adding a new `Column` to a `DataGrid` using the method `addColumn`, you can specify a custom header:

1. [`addColumn(Column<T, ?> col, SafeHtml headerHtml)`](http://www.gwtproject.org/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/user/cellview/client/AbstractCellTable.html#addColumn(com.google.gwt.user.cellview.client.Column,%20com.google.gwt.safehtml.shared.SafeHtml))
2. [`addColumn(Column<T, ?> col, Header<?> header)`](http://www.gwtproject.org/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/user/cellview/client/AbstractCellTable.html#addColumn(com.google.gwt.user.cellview.client.Column,%20com.google.gwt.user.cellview.client.Header))

So you should either pass a `SafeHtml` instance specifying the `title`  attribute (something like `SafeHtmlUtils.fromTrustedString("<span title=\"Title of the header\">Header</span>")`) or create a custom `Header` (or use `SafeHtmlHeader`, which is actually what happens internally when you use `addColumn(Column<T, ?> col, SafeHtml headerHtml)`).